# Using AnkoLogger with levels other than "info"

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I use `AnkoLogger` in my Android project, but it only works when the log level is `info`, other levels logs nothing, but the built-in Android `Log` works well. What can I do to use `AnkoLogger` as a replacement of the built-in one?

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you should file an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be the usage of [`Log.isLoggable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) which by default logs only level `INFO` and above.

There was an [issue created in anko project](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/104) which is now closed:

> `AnkoLogger` uses `Log.isLoggable()` under the hood which ignores VERBOSE
>   and `DEBUG` log levels by default. You can read more about it here:
>   https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/proper-logging-from-android-application/.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread but I stumbled on the same problem recently.

Here is the code from AnkoLogger

```
inline fun AnkoLogger.verbose(message: () -> Any?) {
    val tag = loggerTag
    if (Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.VERBOSE)) {
        Log.v(tag, message()?.toString() ?: "null")
    }
}

[...]

val loggerTag: String
    get() = getTag(javaClass)

[...]

private fun getTag(clazz: Class<*>): String {
    val tag = clazz.simpleName
    return if (tag.length <= 23) {
        tag
    } else {
        tag.substring(0, 23)
    }
}
```

In the method `Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.VERBOSE)`, the variable `tag` is your class name. If you want this check to succeed, you need a prop `className = VERBOSE`.

**Solution:**
To set this prop, you should run `adb shell setprop log.tag.{className} VERBOSE` in the terminal tab in Android Studio (or whichever terminal you are using).

**Comment:**
Unless I am mistaken, you have to do it for each class where you want to see verbose log. I don't have any solution for batch setting the prop for each of my classes in one command. It might be easier to reimplement your own logger class, but that's a whole other question.